# CasperJS: Cannot fully exit test suite with multiple steps

Tags: casperjs

Since the old and stable version of casperjs `1.0.4`. I'm able to exit the whole test if I only call `casper.exit()`. But on `1.1 beta3`, calling `exit()` is not working anymore if you deployed multiple steps on the test suite.

Basically my test is to call the `exit()` once fail. I tried to use the `--fast-fail` but its the same. Also take note that I'm using the extend method.

Here is a sample code, I extend the `Casper` with `Google` to scrape links. This test should fail and exit the test entirely and not to print the links anymore.

```
var Casper = require('casper').Casper;
var utils = require('utils');
var url = "http://google.com";

function Google() {
    Google.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}

utils.inherits(Google, Casper);

var links = [];

Google.prototype.getLinks = function() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("h3.r a");
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        try {
            // google handles redirects hrefs to some script of theirs
            return (/url\?q=(.*)&sa=U/).exec(e.getAttribute("href"))[1];
        } catch (err) {
            return e.getAttribute("href");
        }
    });
};

var google = new Google();

google.test.begin("Google links test", 1, function(test){
    google.start(url, function() {
        // search for 'casperjs' from google form
        this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: "casperjs" }, true);
    });

    google.then(function() {
        // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
        links = this.evaluate(this.getLinks);
        // now search for 'phantomjs' by fillin the form again
        this.waitForSelector('fform[action="/search"]', function(){
            this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: "phantomjs" }, true);
            test.pass("Form found")
        }, function(){
            test.fail('form not found');
            test.abort();
            this.exit();
        }, 5000);

    });

    google.then(function() {
        // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
        links = links.concat(this.evaluate(this.getLinks));
    });

    google.run(function() {
        // echo results in some pretty fashion
        this.echo(links.length + " links found:");
        this.echo(" - " + links.join("\n - "));
        this.exit();
    });
});
```

Comment: You already know it, but for the others, to exit casper with the testing framework : `test.done()`.

Comment: I do not think your answer can help me

Comment: Yes, that's why I said **for other** :p I asked myself the same question and `casper.test.done()` did the trick for me. I just wanted to mention it.